# Combine's Future never completes when flatMapped

Tags: ios, combine

I have the following simple `Future`:

```
class ViewModel {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func test() {
        let trigger = PassthroughSubject<Void, Error>()

       let future =  Future<String, Error> { promise in
                       promise(.success("Future Succeded"))
                   }

        trigger
        .flatMap { future }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print("completion received \(completion)")
        }, receiveValue: { val in
            print("value received \(val)")
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)

        trigger.send(())
    }
}
```

I don't know why it never completes when flat mapped with another publisher (in this case a `PassthroughSubject`), it only produces the value.

when it's not flat mapped it produces the value and completes normally.

Comment: When I change the `flatMap` to `map` and don't make any further changes the completion isn't received either.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior might look weird but it makes a lot of sense. Completing the `Future` does not complete the `PassthroughSubject`. So you can continue sending values through the `PassthroughSubject` which would result in new `Future` instances being created and firing. As a rule, a `Publisher` can only complete or error once. So if completing the `Future` would trigger the `sink` completion closure, that means the `PassthroughSubject` can produce no new values anymore which is not desirable because a `PassthroughSubject` usually never completes (unless you tell it to directly).

Similar to your example, this code also only triggers the completion once:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

(0..<2).publisher
  .flatMap { _ in return (0..<5).publisher }
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print("completion received \(completion)")
  }, receiveValue: { val in
    print("value received \(val)")
  })
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The reason is that the created publisher is one that will publish two values, and then it completes. If the `flatMap` publisher would cause the `sink` completion to be called, that would mean that the `(0..<2)` publisher completes, except it still has values to send so it's not completed.

So long story short, the beginning publisher decides when the stream completes; not the flatmapped publisher.

Comment: Great explanation. Note that you can cause completion in the question’s example by adding `trigger.send(completion: .finished)`.

Comment: Yes, my mental picture is that a publisher produced by `.flatMap` has its `.finished` completion "swallowed" so that it doesn't pass downstream. This makes sense because, as you say, it's not the job of the produced publisher to termination the operation of the pipeline by finishing. — On the other hand, if a produced publisher throws an error, the pipeline _does_ terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had this problem but in turns out it was only because I wasn't holding onto the return value from the publisher. As stated in the docs for `sink()`

> The return value should be held, otherwise the stream will be canceled.

My playground code:

```
var t:Timer?
print(Date())
let _ = Just(33)
    .flatMap { (i) -> Future<Int, Never> in
        return Future<Int, Never> { promise in
            t = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (t) in
                print("Timer!")
                promise(.success(i * i))
            }
        }
    }
    .sink { (i) in
        print("ok")
        print("\(Date()): \(i) received")
    }
```

The timer fires but the sink isn't called. Changing the assignment to ...

```
let pub = Just(33)
```

...solves it.